# jQuery TypeWatch - Extending for empty input?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typewatch

I've created my own autocomplete using ajax and I want to be able to monitor the search input as the user types... I'm using TypeWatch right now and the only issue I see is that if the user has backspaced and the input is now empty, my search results sit there.

What would be the best way of extending the TypeWatch function (perhaps adding a second callback) so that when the input it empty, I can remove the search results div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

In typeWatch.js, add a line to the checkElement() function:

```
  // Fire if text > options.captureLength AND text != saved txt OR if override AND text > options.captureLength, OR if the results are empty and there was a previous search
  if ((elTxt.length > options.captureLength && elTxt.toUpperCase() != timer.text)
  || (override && elTxt.length > options.captureLength)
  || (elTxt.length == 0 && timer.text)
  ) {
    timer.text = elTxt.toUpperCase();
    timer.cb(elTxt);
  }
};
```